# Book about weird things happening in a walled city

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book several years ago.

The setting was in the Pacific Northwest, perhaps in the state of Washington. The city (Seattle? Spokane? Tacoma?) was walled off due to strange things that were happening in it. A couple of characters try to escape and are herded back into the quarantine by the military.

The main characters, I think a couple of teenagers, have to scavenge for supplies. In their wanderings in the city, they find people melded together with inanimate objects, like a leg hanging through a ceiling, a head in a wall, and other such freaky setups. They figure out that something really strange is emanating from the city hospital. There are strange lights and sounds that come from there. It might be guarded by the military, because I think they have to fight their way in to explore what is happening.

Eventually there is something in the sky above the city like a wormhole, and they talk a lot about other dimensions intersecting with their dimension. At the end of the story, you realize this phenomenon is expanding and threatens the whole Earth.

Comment: I think this one might have shown up here before.. and been answered, if I recall correctly. Is the overall plot about magic becoming real in the world?